# How can a Tradingview alert time and lot size differ from the backtest time and lot size results?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, mql5, metatrader5

i have built at bot that generates webhooks off alerts on tradingview and sends them to server then to metatrader 5.  however the alerts that are generated when on a stock chart, that alert info of a trade, is different than what the backtest results are on the Tradingview for that very same trade!
[image]

When trying with FOREX alerts and webhooks and trading Tradingview does almost exactly what its supposed to however, with stocks like AAPL and AMZN there are very clear discrepancies.  We have tried looking at documentation to no avail.

Comment: Strategy script and alert that created from it - it is two differend scripts. So it depends of a strategy code. E.g if strategy calculates only on realtime bars, then while strategy on a chart started to execute some orders, you did not create alert yet, and after you did - the script and alert might be desynchronized already, because of the different starting points